# Postgres Count Where ILIKE vs Postgres Count Where to_tsvector

Tags: postgresql

Postgres version: PostgreSQL 12.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42), 64-bit

I have a big performance differences between 2 counts on a table without relationships and 2.1 Mil records.
If I use count with `ILIKE` it takes 1.6s, if i make count with `to_tsvector` it takes 10s.

The row `address` is indexed and the row `address_un` is also indexed with gin:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_order_archives_address_un ON order_archives USING gin ( (to_tsvector('English', address_un::text))) ;
```

The count with `ILIKE`:

```
SELECT count('id') FROM "order_archives"  WHERE  address ILIKE '%street%';
```

The count with full text search:

```
Select count('id') From order_archives Where to_tsvector('English', address_un::text) @@ to_tsquery('English', 'street:*')
```

I saw this kind of performance differences sometimes using `order by`
Can you explain me why the full text search with count is taking so much?

Update:

Explain Like query:
[image]

Explain full text search query:
[image]

Comment: Please show the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for both plans.

Comment: @jjanes I added 2 pictures, thank you

Comment: It's better to show the output of **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) and you should add it as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) screenshots are really hard to read. When adding the text output make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please post text.  Whatever tool you used to generate the images has obscured some of the most important information, like buffer usage and actual time.

You seem to be counting the entire table (Rows removed by filter: 0) so it not surprising that using an index scan to read the whole table is counter productive.  I don't know why every single address in your database contains 'street' (none of my last 4 addresses did, for example).  I think you might be indexing structured data, but in a silly way that indexes the keys rather than the values.

Also, your table seems to be poorly vacuumed.  Or at least, I don't know what else explains your bitmap index scan having twice as many rows as your bitmap heap scan, but with no rows removed by filter or recheck.